# How to automatically turn on the screen on double touch of turned-off screen?

Tags: screen, android-10, touchscreen, android-11, sensors

Is it possible to turn on my Android 10 phone's (Samsung Galaxy S9) screen like my Android 11 tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S6), by double touching the turned-off screen? Or when detecting that it has been lifted up or somehow it changed its orientation a little bit?

I've searched this website but did not find something useful.

Comment: Only some ROM developers add that feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Lift to wake" from:
Settings -> Advanced features -> Motions and gestures

That's a feature in Samsung's OneUI.

Comment: Please mention your device and/or ROM. It's not a stock Android's feature.

Comment: @IrfanLatif That's a feature in Samsung's OneUI.

Answer (score 1):

You have two other options in addition to what Omar mentioned.

*Settings > Display > Navigation Bar > Hard Press Home Button*

With this activated, there's an area at the bottom of the display, that when pressed, will wake the screen.

Also, if you set the Always on Display to 'Tap to Show', it will wake the Always on Display (might not be what you're wanting though).

*Settings > Lock Screen > Always On Display*